React Native useState Variable is read-only
I am having a state with a default value of true i.e. const [passShow, setShow] = useState(true). I am trying to show the password when the state is false and hide it when it is true on my textInput. However, I am getting an error that says passShow is read-only. Please see the attached code below
import { View, Text, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Pressable } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import logo from '../assets/client.png'
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
import { Link } from 'expo-router'

const app = () => {
    const [ passShow, setShow] = useState(true);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView className='flex-1'>
        <View className="flex-1 items-center justify-between bg-white">
            <View className='mt-36'>
                <Image source={logo} style={{width: 150, height: 96}}/>
                <Text className="text-xl py-5 mt-2 font-bold text-left w-11/12">Sign In to your Account</Text>
            </View>

            <View className='w-full items-center'>
                <View className="w-11/12 my-2">
                    <Text>Customer ID</Text>
                    <TextInput cursorColor={'#cc0000'} className="w-full border-gray-100 border-2 border-solid p-1 mt-2 rounded-lg" />
                </View>
                <View className="w-11/12 my-2">
                    <Text>Password</Text>
                    <TextInput cursorColor={'#cc0000'} secureTextEntry={passShow} className="w-full border-gray-100 border-2 border-solid p-1 mt-2 rounded-lg" />
                    <View className='flex-row justify-between '>
                        <Pressable onPress={() => setShow(!passShow)}><Text>Show Password</Text></Pressable>
                        <Pressable><Text className="text-themeRed my-2">Reset Password</Text></Pressable>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <TouchableOpacity className='bg-themeRed w-11/12 py-3 px-2 items-center rounded-lg mt-3'>
                    <Text className='text-white'>Sign In</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                
                <Link href='/signup' className='flex-row w-11/12 py-3'>
                    <Text>Don't have an Account? </Text>
                    <Text className='text-themeRed ml-1.5'>Sign Up</Text>
                </Link>
            </View>

            <View className='mb-5 items-center'>
                <Text className='text-gray-400'>24/7 support 076 979 0642 | helpdesk@ctecg.co.za</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default app

I tried using the state variable to try and change the text from 'Show Password' in the following way:
{() => passShow ? <Text>Show Password</Text> : <Text>Hide Password</Text>}
I get the same error

Your code looks fine to me. Are you sure you are not modifying it somewhere like this: passShow = false?

{() => passShow ? <Text>Show Password</Text> : <Text>Hide Password</Text>} This is wrong, but I don't think it's related to your error. But it should be fixed to be just something like: {passShow ? <Text>Show Password</Text> : <Text>Hide Password</Text>}. And regarding to your error, same like what janziemba mentioned, make sure whenever you update the state, you use the setState action (in your case setShow), and do not reassign like passShow = false

Thank you for your response. I checked through the react native docs and found a solution. apparently my state's initial value should be false. Then secureTextEntry={!showPass} instead of setting it to true and secureTextEntry={showPass} I am not sure why. But it worked. Thanks
